# Blow-up of solutions to Euler-type ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-calculus

Let $\ell\in \mathbb{N}$, $a>2$, $C<0$ and $D \in [0,\infty)$. Consider the function $f: [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ solving

$$[r(r-2/a)f'(r)]' = \frac{f(r) - D}{r(r-2/a)}+ \ell(\ell+1)f(r)$$
$$f(1) = 0, \quad f'(1) = C$$

It can easily be shown that either $f$ goes to $\pm \infty$ or $f$ goes to $0$. If $D=0$, we can easily show using calculus that $f$ goes to $-\infty$. I think it can also be shown that there exists a unique $D$ such that $f$ goes to $0$.

How do I find an expression (or at least an estimate) of $D = D(a, C, \ell)$ in which the solution goes to $0$? Are there common methods or tools used to do such things for this type of ODE?